# Change selection highlight color in Microsoft Visio Pro 2016 x64

Tags: microsoft-visio, appearance, microsoft-visio-2016

In Visio 2010, if I selected, for example, a group of lines, the highlight in those lines to show that they were selected would be a thin, bright pink line.

I just installed Visio Pro 2016 x64.  There that bright pink line is changed to a dark blue which is almost invisible between the default black lines I have selected.

Is there any way to change the default color of the highlight lines to something useful, such as pink… The way it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use RegEdit to change this.

In Visio 2010 the appropriate setting is stored in:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Visio\Colors\ColorManySelect**

so in Visio 2016 it should be in:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Visio\Colors\ColorManySelect**

The value for the pink used in Visio 2010 is **255 100 255**.