# Visio 2010 'selection handle box' line properties

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

Can the Visio 2010 selection box properties be changed?

This is not the shape itself, but is the box with the handles that appears when you click on a shape.  Mine is a light blue dashed line.  Normally this would be fine, but myadd-in uses that in its' search feature.  So the light blue dash line is nearly invisible in the midst of a complex drawing and this renders the search feature practically useless.  Something more like solid bold red would be more appropriate.

[image]

I found this article, but it does not address this particular line property.
[Change selection highlight color in Microsoft Visio Pro 2016 x64](https://superuser.com/questions/1170901/change-selection-highlight-color-in-microsoft-visio-pro-2016-x64)

Answer (score 0):

No, the selection handle box colour cannot be changed.

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Or is it just that you haven't found a way to do it?