# Change Selection Highlight Color in Microsoft Visio O365

Tags: colors, microsoft-visio, highlighting

I now Visio O365 installed, and I have a question: Is it possible to change the color of the highlighted area when doing a Ctrl F to search for something?

I have tons of information on multiple pages, and some are duplicates. If I select Ctrl + F to search for key characters, it defaults to a gray highlighted selection. If the item I'm looking for is on the page more than once, I can arrow through and find where it's at. However, if it's only on the page once, it's often incredibly difficult to find just exactly where that small, gray box resides. What would be good is if I could change it from gray to, say, yellow or red - anything really that would make it stand out.

I thought I found the answer to this here:

[Change selection highlight color in Microsoft Visio Pro 2016 x64](https://superuser.com/questions/1170901/change-selection-highlight-color-in-microsoft-visio-pro-2016-x64)

However, I've seemingly put all of the color RGBs into an app and cannot find one gray option. I thought it might be ColorManySelect or ColorLinkHighlight, but these do not appear to be what I'm looking for.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Visio, data found by "ctrl + f" cannot be highlighted as other colors.

This feature is only available in Excel and Word.

As a workaround, I suggest you color shapes according to data.

You can find what you need based on the color changes in the shapes.

1.On the Data tab, click to select the Data Graphic Fields check box.

2.In the Data Graphic Fields pane, identify which field of data you want to apply coloring to.

More information :

[Color shapes according to their data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/color-shapes-according-to-their-data-fa42a92f-019d-4baa-940e-e477b9b9dfeb?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: Thank you, Binggo, but you may have misunderstood the question. I'm not trying to permanently highlight something as you would in Excel. What I'm trying to do is - as I perform a search within a Visio diagram and it highlights what it found - easily "see" where that highlighted selection is. I have SO much data on a sheet/tab that it's easier to do a Ctrl F. The problem is that black font on a white background is fine, but the gray selection that's highlighted when it finds something is often difficult to locate. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: There's no such feature in Visio. It is a workaround. When you find the cells you need to highlight, you can go back.